# Add Union to increase efficiency in VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have code within a workbook that works exactly how I want it to, but I am looking for ways to increase its efficiency/speed.  My thought would be to add a union for all blank rows and hide that range all at once.  Can this be done?

```
    Sub HideRws()
   Dim Rng As Range, Cl As Range
   With Sheet3
      For Each Cl In .Range("A11:A60")
         Cl.EntireRow.Hidden = Cl.Value = ""
      Next Cl
      For Each Rng In .Range("A71:A120, A131:A180, A190:A239").Areas
         If Rng(1) = "" Then
            Rng.Offset(-6).Resize(58).EntireRow.Hidden = True
         Else
            For Each Cl In Rng
               Cl.EntireRow.Hidden = Cl.Value = ""
            Next Cl
         End If
      Next Rng
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the goal of your macro?

Comment: If you are looking to make improvements and efficiencies to existing, working code, you will want to check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think you can set areas for blank cells, if you just want to quickly hide blank rows, use the specialcells. `Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: See the `CombineRanges` function (and how it's being used) in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/139624/23788).

Comment: wouldn't a union basically do the same thing?

Comment: @Hery0502 To answer your very specific question: Yes, you can do what you want to do with a union. Whether or not it is efficient with your data set, or more efficient than one solution over another, is really only something you can test. This forum can provide guidelines, but if you're worried about milliseconds, you should probably run comparison tests.

Comment: Depending on the size of the data set and the number of rows matching the criteria, Davesexcel and @StoneGiant's `SpecialCells` solution might very well be more efficient than a `Union`. I second StoneGiant's comment here, given two horses, the only way to find out which is the fastest, is to race them.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does the same thing:

```
Sub HideRows()
    With Sheet3
        .Range("A11:A60").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        For Each Rng In .Range("A71:A120, A131:A180, A190:A239").Areas
            If Rng(1) = "" Then
                Rng.Offset(-6).Resize(58).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next Rng
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @QHarr comparing a cell's value against *either* `vbNullString` or `""` always worries me; it assumes the worksheet only contains values that can be represented as a string. This bites so many people, so often. `#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, or `#REF!` have no valid string representation; comparing them to `""` or `vbNullString` would throw a *type mismatch* run-time error.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Very good point. Let me delete and change that. Hadn't thought about all the error bits before. Eek. Stern letter to self.

Comment: Why bother with the resize - unnecessary operation in this case.

Comment: The resize part of the code hides a range that is larger than the specific range of A71:A120.  In other words, if cell A71 is "", then it hides range A65:122.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I agree with you. It was not my intent to fix the comparison or rewrite Hery0502's code. I only wanted to show how the special cells search could be used to eliminate two unnecessary loops as an efficiency boost.

Comment: @StoneGiant - I appreciate the input.  When I tried your code, it gave me a run time error 1004 - Application- defined or object-defined error.

Comment: My guess is that it is the line that says "With Sheet3", which I took from your original post. If I make that line `With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")` the code works fine for me. If not that line, which line is giving you trouble?

Comment: ...also, apparently SpecialCells throws a trappable error if it finds no matching cells. So you'll want to handle that too.

Comment: @StoneGiant - I receive a run time error 9 - subscript out of range.  The highlighted row is With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").

Comment: I don't know. Sorry. I'm out of ideas.